# Why is this lazy iterable resolving more than once?

Tags: asynchronous, promise, dart, lazy-evaluation

I ran into this with some production code today and was able to fix it with a simple `.toList()` to resolve the lazyList before waiting, but I don't understand WHY it works this way and *only* when using `Future.wait()` what's going on here? Why is the lazyList being resolved twice?

[Play with it on DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6bdf91b6ed90bec353845c0a4a11bdc4) (change the value of `doWait` on line 3 and see the different results)

---

#### Code

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var executedTracker  = [];
  var source           = ["a", "b", "c"];

  List promises = source.map((item) async {
    print('executing item $item${(executedTracker.contains(item) ? ' (again!? o_O)' : '')}'); executedTracker.add(item);
    return (item*2);
  });

  Future.wait(promises).whenComplete(() {
    print('--------\nAll promises complete.');
    print('Processing ${promises.length} results...\n');
    promises.forEach((promise) => null /* do a thing with the result*/);
  });
}
```

#### Output

```
executing item a
executing item b
executing item c

All promises complete.
Processing 3 results...

executing item a (again!? o_O)
executing item b (again!? o_O)
executing item c (again!? o_O)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you iterate `promises` twice, once in `Future.wait(promises)` and once with `promises.forEach(...)`.
(You got lucky with `promises.length` - because the mapped iterable knows that it is based on a list, it doesn't iterate once more to find the length.)

Each iteration of a mapped iterable will re-iterate the original iterable and perform the map operation again, that's what it means to be a lazy transformation. Being lazy is necessary for cases like `hugelyGiganticIterable.map(something).take(10).toList()`. If it wasn't lazy, it would perform the map on all the elements in the hugely gigantic iterable (it could even be infinite, iterables can be infinite, unlike lists).

What you would likely want to do in a real example is to use the results of the `Future.wait(promises)` operation:

```dart
Future.wait(promises).then((items) {
  print('--------\nAll promises complete.');
  print('Processing ${items.length} results...\n');
  items.forEach((item) => null /* do a thing with the *result* */);
});
```

If you don't actually *want* the lazy behavior, then you should collect the values eagerly. You do that, e.g., by writing:

```dart
List promises = source.map((item) async {
  ...
}).toList();  // <-- notice the ".toList()"!
```

Using `toList` forces the evaluation of every mapped element of the iterable, removing the lazyness.

Comment: Why does the lazyList not stay resolved after the first time? Why re-evaluate the contents of the list every time we need it? That seems like it would obliterate any performance savings we got from lazy-izing the list in the first place. Also, I'd love to use the results of the wait, like you suggest, but those are only passed to `.then()` and `.catchError()` and in my particular case, I need to be using `.whenComplete()` which provides no arguments to the callback.

Comment: It's not a list, it's an iterable. It could buffer the result, but another property of being lazy is that changes to the underlying list will be reflected the next time you iterate. If you update the list after iterating two elements from the mapped iterable, the next iteration should not see two stale values. This ensures a consistent behavior. If you do want something to be executed only once, add an `.toList()` at the end. That gets you out of the lazyness and eagerly creates all the values.

Comment: The result of `Future.wait` is only available in the `then`-branch because in the error branch, there is on result. the error prevented that. Trying to do something with the results in a `whenComplete` handler will not work if there is an error, so you should put the actual work that uses the results in the `then` handler, because tthat's the only case where you know that there *is* a result to work with.

Comment: you make some excellent points about why the lazyIterator would not want to cache the already-resolved elements. Thank you!